# Issue to display other dart files with flutter on my device

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, android-studio, dart

I've got an issue and i hope someone could help me.
I'm developping a flutter app on visual studio. My main.dart file seems to be connected
with my device but when i try to display another file in the device. Its the main.dart file
that is display again and again.
Do you know a way to display other dart files on the device?

Hope to hear an answer from you guys.

PS: Sorry for my terrible english

Comment: What does "display another file" mean?  Your app has only one main(), and that's in main.dart.  The other files are compiled into the app, being called at the proper time from main.

Comment: Thanks you for you answer, I'm a newbie with flutter. I have a file named main.dart, this file is the home page of my app. I'm coding some widgets on other file that i want to be display on the emulated phone screen. But the emulated phone screen display just on the screen my main.dart file not my others files. This what i try to say with "display another file". I don't know if i'm very clear  sorry if i'm not.

Comment: You can change the "body:" of your Scaffold to construct any widget you want, including ones that you define in other files, presuming you have the right import().

Comment: Oh ok i see. Makes sense, i think i will construct my widgets as you said in the body of my Scaffold in my main.dart. But i was thinking it was possible to display any files on the screen even if they aren't the main file. Currently i'm working on my login page. According to you should i coding in my main file then copy/paste it on another file? Thanks you for your advice.